# Ionic 3 build error

Tags: ionic3

Galera tenho um projeto feito em IONIC 3 de uma hora para outra não faz mais o build.
Segue a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Galera resolvi da seguinte forma: exclui o projeto local e refiz o download do meu repositorio.

Comment: Não é necessário escrever uma resposta apenas pra dizer "obrigado". A melhor maneira de agradecer é **[aceitando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** a resposta que te ajudou. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/138867)

Comment: A onde que escrevi a resposta como "obrigado"? Pois resposta acima esta a maneira que consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho visto esse problema acontecendo com algumas pessoas em fóruns. Ainda não sei a causa do problema mas aqui vai algumas possíveis soluções:

- Instalar o ionic novamente na versão 3.15.0 que parece estar estável `npm install  ionic@3.15.0  --save` ou tentar instalar a ultima versão `npm install ionic@latest -g`
- Fazer update do android studio
- Fazer update pro nodejs 7
- Fazer o downgrade da apiLevel do android em `platforms/android/project.properties`
- Tentar rodar o app em outro emulador ou device.

Tem uma discussão rolando [aqui](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982/88).

E também [um dos commiters](https://twitter.com/jcesarmobile/status/923312847970619393) do cordova postou algo que talvez possa ser relacionado:

> Android studio 3 is out. Breaks @apachecordova again. Stay tuned for
>   next cordova-android 6.4.0

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Delete o projeto e baixei de novo do repositorio.

Comment: Boa, poste isso como resposta então para ajudar outras pessoas.