# Erro ao gerar build em modo release no ionic

Tags: ionic3

Desenvolvi uma aplicação ionic 3. Todas as builds em modo debug foram geradas corretamente, porém ao tentar gerar o apk em modo release está dando erro.

Ionic Info:

[image: Ionic Info]
Erro ao gerar o apk:
[image: Erro]
Já testei apagando a pasta node_modules e instalando novamente com o comando npm install.

Também testei removendo as plataformas ios e android e adicionando novamente.

Por favor, me ajudem aí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi do erro, me parece um problema com o Node

"... withou a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handler with .catch() ..."

Tenta instalar uma versão anterior do Node através do NVM pra ver se funciona.

Comment: Agora deu o erro abaixo:

(node:25384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to prepare plug-in f
or android :
An unexpected error occurred. Contact IBM support.
(node:25384) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
 that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Daneil, tenta dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250486/ionic-3-build-error?rq=1

Comment: O apk em modo debug gerou normal,  mas em release deu outros erros: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.

Comment: Após remover a plataforma Android e adicionar novamente, porém com a versão 6.15.0 funcionou, gerou o apk em modo release. Agora tentando assinar o apk, está dando erro: keytool não é reconhecido como um comando interno...

Comment: tenta isso: https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/package/android.html
ou isso: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algumas pesquisas consegui resolver, apagando a plataforma Android e adicionando novamente, porém na versão 6.15.0.
Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.